# NotifyOnPropertyChange realization

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I implement  NotifyOnPropertyChange method? To call it from the inheritors ViewModelBase could be as:

```
NotifyOnPropertyChange (() => Property)
```

The input to this method is applied lambda expression that specifies a property of change which need to notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation can look like this. It's implemented using `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace.

```
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> lambda)
        {
            dynamic l = lambda.Body;
            string propertyName = l.Member.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
```

Here's an example of the whole class.

```
    public class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _someProperty;

        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get { return _someProperty; }
            set
            {
                _country = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SomeProperty);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }



        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> lambda)
        {
            dynamic l = lambda.Body;
            string propertyName = l.Member.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

The full blown implementation without using dynamic would look like this:

```
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> lambda)
        {
            if (lambda == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("lambda");

            var memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression.","lambda");

            var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
            if (property == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression. Expression must be a property.", "lambda");

            // check if the property is not static
            var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
            if (getMethod.IsStatic) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression. Property cannot be static.", "propertyExpression");

            string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this so you don't have to give the property name at all (as long as it's called directly from the property setter). This way, there is no fear of renaming properties or typos.

```
private void NotifyOnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

Then, implement your property like so:

```
string _somePropertyValue;

string SomeProperty
{
    get { return _somePropertyValue; }
    set 
    { 
        if(_somePropertyValue != value)
        {
            _somePropertyValue = value;
            NotifyOnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In builds in Release mode when code optimization is performed this can fail.

Comment: @BartoszWójtowicz Do you have documentation to support that? I've used this method in several support libraries and various applications and have never had it fail on me.  I've never seen property setters "optimized" away.

Comment: It should not fail - I would expect code optimization to actually adhere to the C# language specifications, you know.

Comment: Indeed CallerMemberNameAttribute is a new Microsoft's attribute added in .Net 4.5 as part for mscorlib. It should not fail. However, the way you raise the event is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NotificationObject` from [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) library. It's already implemented there as `RaisePropertyChanged<T>`

Here're links to the source code for the [`NotificationObject`](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V4/PrismLibrary/Desktop/Prism/ViewModel/NotificationObject.cs) and for the [`PropertySupport`](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V4/PrismLibrary/Desktop/Prism/ViewModel/PropertySupport.cs) classes.